# Search for strings in a for loop without referencing each string individually in the loop

Tags: python, string, pandas, search, dataframe

I have text data to categorise. Using a for loop in which I specify individual strings, I'm identifying if particular words or phrases are present in rows of another column. Where true, the loop appends a specific value to a new list. The new list is then added to the `DataFrame`. However this approach is too unwieldy for my actual data as I need to specify numerous strings for numerous tests.

Is there a way I can group individual strings within single data structures which the loop can search inside of? Meaning each test in the loop would reference just one data structure as opposed to individual strings as spelt out inside the loop. Can this be done?

Below is a reproducible example of what I'm currently doing, highlighting the issue.

```
    data = {
        'opinion': ['He said it was too expensive',
                      'She said it was too costly',
                      'He thought it was not fast enough',
                      'They thought is was not right and too much money',
                      'Her view was that it was too small and too slow', 
                   ]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['opinion'])
df
```

Creates this:

```
    opinion
0   He said it was too expensive
1   She said it was too costly
2   He thought it was not fast enough
3   They thought is was not right and too much money
4   Her view was that it was too small and too slow
```

Then this for loop does the following categorisation.

```
new_col=[]

for row in df['opinion']:
    if 'too expensive' in row or 'too costly' in row or 'too much money' in row:
        new_col.append('Too Expensive')
    elif 'not fast enough' in row or 'too slow' in row:
        new_col.append('Too Slow')

df['reason'] = new_col
df

    opinion                                           reason
0   He said it was too expensive                      Too Expensive
1   She said it was too costly                        Too Expensive
2   He thought it was not fast enough                 Too Slow
3   They thought is was not right and too much money  Too Expensive
4   Her view was that it was too small and too slow   Too Slow
```

In my actual data though I can't write scores of individual strings inside of the loop for every test, there's just too many.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could keep your terms in a `list` of `dictionaries`, where the `keys` are the `replacement` and the `values` contain `lists` with the words `to_replace`.

```
words = [{'Too Expensive': ['too expensive', 'too costly', 'too much money'],
      'Too Slow': ['not fast enough', 'too slow']}]
```

Then `loop` over `words`, use `str.contains` with a `regex` that looks at all `to_replace` at once, and `.loc[]` to identify and assign.

```
for word in words:
    for replacement, to_replace in word.items():
        df.loc[df.opinion.str.contains('|'.join(to_replace)), 'reason'] = replacement
```

to get:

```
                                            opinion         reason
0                      He said it was too expensive  Too Expensive
1                        She said it was too costly  Too Expensive
2                 He thought it was not fast enough       Too Slow
3  They thought is was not right and too much money  Too Expensive
4   Her view was that it was too small and too slow       Too Slow
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
test_strings = ['too expensive', 'too costly', 'too much money']
for row in df['opinion']:
    for tester in test_strings:
        if tester in row:
            new_col.append("Too Expensive")
            break
```

Comment: You forget for `Too Slow`.

Comment: I thought an MWE was enough :)

Answer (score 0):

i think using RegEx would be more convinient in this case:

```
df['reason'] = ''

df.ix[df.opinion.str.lower().str.contains(r'too\s+(?:expensive|costly|much money)'), 'reason'] = 'Too Expensive'

df.ix[df.opinion.str.lower().str.contains(r'(?:not fast enough|too slow)'), 'reason'] = 'Too Slow'

In [309]: df
Out[309]:
                                            opinion         reason
0                      He said it was too expensive  Too Expensive
1                        She said it was too costly  Too Expensive
2                 He thought it was not fast enough       Too Slow
3  They thought is was not right and too much money  Too Expensive
4   Her view was that it was too small and too slow       Too Slow
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has a fast solution for applying a function to rows, so .apply is pretty much designed for this. Ideally, vectorizing is the fastest but I can't think of a way to do that. .apply is after that and iterating on the rows is the slowest so its best to avoid it if possible.

Also, you probably want to use a dictionary for your list of keywords as a convenient way to scale up your list of potential keywords.

```
def categorizer(x):
main_dict = {"too much money":"too expensive", "too expensive":"too expensive", "too costly":"too expensive", "too slow":"too slow", "not fast enough": "not fast enough"}
for key in main_dict:
    if key in x:
        return main_dict[key]
df["Category"] = df["opinion"].apply(lambda x:categorizer(x))
```

Comment: Doesn't `.apply` just do the iteration for you? I didn't think it was faster than iteration.

Comment: Nah, .apply works on a row/column basis. .applymap is what you are thinking of, it operates on an elementwise basis. You can get quite significant speed gains on big data sets using .apply vs iterrows